# ReactJS Website not building in AzureDevOps working fine locally

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-devops

I have a reactJS App which is working fine locally. But recently the build is failing when the same code is build via pipeline on AzureDevOps.

Can one please let me know why this could be?

Please find below the npm run build task logs from the build instance,

```
Starting: npm run build
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and 
authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.169.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
/usr/local/bin/npm --version
6.14.5
/usr/local/bin/npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.5 node/v12.18.0 linux x64"

; environment configs
userconfig = "/home/vsts/work/1/npm/20420.npmrc"

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/vsts/work/1/s/client

/usr/local/bin/npm run build
error Generating JavaScript bundles failed


[BABEL] /home/vsts/work/1/s/client/.cache/production-app.js: No "exports" main resolved in 
/home/vsts/work/1/s/client/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/package.json
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! website-company@0.1.0 build: `cross-env GATSBY_THEME=brand gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the website-company@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-06-11T05_31_44_848Z-debug.log
> website-company@0.1.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s/client
> cross-env GATSBY_THEME=brand gatsby build

2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~prebuild: website-company@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: website-company@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: PATH: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-
```

bin:/home/vsts/work/1/s/client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/share/rust/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
    9 verbose lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: CWD: /home/vsts/work/1/s/client
    10 silly lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'cross-env GATSBY_THEME=brand 
    gatsby build' ]
    11 silly lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle website-company@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script

```
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm- 
lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid website-company@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/vsts/work/1/s/client
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-1083-azure
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error website-company@0.1.0 build: `cross-env GATSBY_THEME=brand gatsby build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the website-company@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
Finishing: npm run build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> production-app.js: No "exports" main resolved in 
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/client/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/package.json

According to the error message, it seems the issue from a regression in `Node.js` or the version of `babel`, please try to following suggestions to resolve this issue:

- Update @babel deps to v7.8.7
- Use Node < v12.16
- Removing the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file then
  run npm install to fresh install all packages

You could check [this thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11216) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leo. Deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and re-installing the packages did resolve the issue